# Smallest modular tensor category with a multiplicity

Tags: modular-tensor-categories

I wrote a 6j-inator taking the multiplication table of a based ring and calculating the equations in the 6j symbols. I successfully tested it with a small example (of the paper "On Classification of Modular Tensor Categories").

But I also want to test if the 6j-inator works when multiplicities are present, and what arbitrary phase parameters are introduced by that. Thus I need a "small" modular tensor category. (Define "small" as "as few different 6j symbols as possible".) [rank<=4](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/9pv08032) still has no multiplicities, [rank=5](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280243302_On_Classification_of_Modular_Categories_by_Rank) lists no multiplication tables. Can anyone help me out? Rank may be even higher, as I said, the number of free variables is limiting for my ability to solve the system.

Comment: There’s the center of E6 with rank 10 that has miltiplicities, but that’s probably too big.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.5761.pdf

Comment: @NoahSnyder: Maybe. The article also gives the writhe data, and I could first handle the FxF part, and the multiplicities are very "localized", so maybe it's not completely hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are interested testing your program for 6j symbols 'only'. If that is the case, you do not need a full modular tensor category. A small example that I know derives from `the' $su(3)_3$ modular tensor category, by modding out $\mathbb{Z}_3$, i.e., $su(3)_3/\mathbb{Z}_3$, which is not modular. This example has one multiplicity, namely 2, rank four, and the number of 6j symbols is 178. For more details, see my answer to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310522/58345), which contains a link to a paper with more information.